# use SSHFS to mount Synology NAS

Tags: mount, nas, synology

I want to mount my home folder on a Synology NAS. I can SSH to the NAS but when I try `sshfs`, I get this error '`read: Connection reset by peer`'.  I used the following command:

```
sshfs john@146.32.56.78:/volume1/homes/john /my_nas -p 1919
```

I also tried this path: `/var/services/homes/john`, but had no success.

How can I find/debug the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just enable the SFTP Service in Control Panel->File Services.

Then mount with sshfs username@machine:/homes/username /directory

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To add to the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347036/194761) from @vindolin (..I don't have enough reputation just to add a comment),

As well as enabling SFTP, you also need to enable permissions to FTP for the specified user.  If that permission isn't enabled, you will continue to get the `connection reset by peer` error.

[image: Screenshot of DSM FTP permission dialogue]

Comment: This does seem to be adding a further answer as well, so maybe more than a comment.

Comment: I don't know if something's changed in a later version of DSM, but I seem to be able to use sshfs fine by just enabling SFTP without the FTP application permission enabled for that user.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add `-o sshfs_debug` to your command to get some debugging information for `sshfs`.

If that doesn't give you more detailed information, use any of

```
-o LogLevel=VERBOSE
-o LogLevel=DEBUG
-o LogLevel=DEBUGX  # with X being 1, 2 or 3
```

for increasing `ssh` verbosity.